# handlebars not loading the content to the page

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

When I load the page, the contents from the handlebar don't appear. But when I check the elements in the console, it is written there but it just doesn't show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.html :

```
<script id="post-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each post}}
     <ul>
       <li><img src="{{url}}"></li>
       <li>{{caption}}</li>
       <li>Username: {{author}}</li>
     </ul>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

main.js :

```
function loadPeople() {
    fetch('people.json')
    .then(
        function(response) {
            return response.json();
        }
    )
    .then(
        function(data) {
            loadPost("post-template", data);
        }
    )
}

function loadPost (targetid, post) {
    let target = document.getElementById(targetid);
    let template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("post-template").textContent);
    let list = template({'post': post});
    
    target.innerHTML = list;
}

window.onload = function() {
    loadPeople();
};
```

people.json :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "art.jpg",
        "caption": "art",
        "author": "John Doe",
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "art.jpg",
        "caption": "art",
        "author": "John Doe",
    }
]


function loadPost (targetid, post) {
    let target = document.getElementById(targetid);
    let template = Handlebars.compile(document.getElementById("post-script").innerHTML);
    let list = template({'post': post});
 
   
    target.innerHTML = list;
}

loadPost("post-template", data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<div id='post-template'></div>


<script id="post-script" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   {{#each post}}
     <ul>
       <li><img src="{{url}}"></li>
       <li>{{caption}}</li>
       <li>Username: {{author}}</li>
     </ul>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

This code worked for me, you had two element with the same id. Change the ID of the script

Comment: okay i feel stupid. thank you for pointing that out! it works now